# Custom Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a GridView like this one:

[image]

But, I don't know how! I know how work with Android GridView, but not like this one.
Suggestions of library or any tip will be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a GridView like this one

The `View` you are referring to can quite easily be created *without* using a `GridView`. If your components (clothing, bags, shoes etc.) are static, you can use nested `LinearLayouts (with weights)` inside a `ScrollView`.

> Suggestions of library or any tip will be welcome.

You can try StaggeredGridView: [Link](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

A demo project to get you going: [Link](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo)